# How to locate a virtual machine files in my local disk VMware

Tags: vmware, vmware-player

I have a virtual machine running on VMware (VMware Workstation 12 player). I accidentally removed it from my inventory instead of deleting from disk. Now, where can I find the files on my local disk so that I can release the disk space..

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The default location for virtual machine files is the folder My Virtual Machines in the My Documents folder of the home directory of the user who created the virtual machines. If you are logged in as this user, you can:

1. Select Start>Run. The Run dialog appears.
2. Type %userprofile%
3. Click OK to see the home directory.

If you are still unable to locate the virtual machine files, you must search the host hard drive for virtual machine configuration files.

To search the host hard drive:

1. Open a command prompt.
2. Enter this command:
3. C:>dir *.vmx /s/p

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried the two approaches. but My virtual machines folder in my documents is already empty and the command to find the directories says 'File not found'. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried searching for other variations? "vmdk, vmem"

Answer (score 0):

Every virtual machine has a directory with multiple files in it, including vm* files (vmdk, vmx, vmem etc.). The default path is under the user's "Documents" directory, in a directory named "Virtual Machines". For removal just delete the relevant machine's directory.

Comment: I tried that, but the 'virtual machines' folder in my 'Documents' is empty.

Comment: I would try searching "vmdk" and "vmem" in the root directory (C:), those are usually the heavy files, and once you find those you find the VM directory